# Associations in sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've read through all the documentation and googled it a ton and I still can't figure this out. I'm trying to setup a database that allows users to be able to create an event/activity and assign multiple tags to it (indoors, food, breakfast) to categorize the events. I'm using postgres and sequelize. I'm also unsure of how I would query these events. Would I use app.get?

Currently I have an activities table and a tags table and a 3rd join table.

Tags table:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Tag = sequelize.define('Tag', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Tag.hasMany(models.Activity, { through: models.ActivityTag, foreignKey: 'tag_id' });
      }
    }
  });
  return Tag;
};
```

Activities table:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Activity = sequelize.define('Activity', {
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
    location: DataTypes.STRING,
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    cost: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        console.log(models);
        Activity.belongsToMany(models.Tag, {as: 'activity' through: models.ActivityTag, foreignKey: 'activity_id' });

      }
    }
  });
  return Activity;
};
```

Join table:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var ActivityTag = sequelize.define('ActivityTag', {
    activity_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    tag_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {

      }
    }
  });
  return ActivityTag;
};
```

Comment: Please explain the relationship between tag and activity, is it 1:1 or 1:N?

Comment: @Rahul It's N:M, note the join table.

Comment: have you written your migrations? does the `associate` class method get called in your application code? your syntax is Sequelize v3 so you should also ensure you're not using Sequelize v4